# cannot read `struct direct` as shown in K&R2

Tags: c, linux

An example of implementing own `readdir` as shown in [K&R2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_MAX 14 /*longest filenames component; system-dependent */

#ifndef DIRSIZ
#define DIRSIZ 14
#endif

typedef struct {
    long ino; /*inode number */
    char name[NAME_MAX+1]; /*name + '\0' terminator */
} my_dirent;

typedef struct {
    int fd; /* file descriptor for directory */
    my_dirent d; /*the directory entry */
} MY_DIR;

/*
 * opendir: open a directory for readdir calls 
 */
MY_DIR *my_opendir(char *dirname)
{
    int fd;
    struct stat stbuf;
    MY_DIR *dp;

    if((fd = open(dirname, O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1
        || fstat(fd, &stbuf) == -1
        || (stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT) != S_IFDIR
        || (dp = malloc(sizeof(MY_DIR))) == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    dp->fd = fd;
    return dp;
}

/*
 * closedir: close directory opened by opendir 
 */
void my_closedir(MY_DIR *dp)
{
    if(dp) {
        close(dp->fd);
        free(dp);
    }
}

#include <sys/dir.h>
/*
 * readdir: read directory entries in sequence 
 */
my_dirent *my_readdir(MY_DIR *dp)
{
    struct direct dirbuf; /* local directory structure */
    static my_dirent d; /* portable structure */

    // HERE BELOW: the body of while loop never executes (I have no idea why) so NULL is returned and causes segfault when dereferencing in printf
    while(read(dp->fd, (char*) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
        if(dirbuf.d_ino == 0) /* slot not in use */
            continue;
        d.ino = dirbuf.d_ino;
        strncpy(d.name, dirbuf.d_name, DIRSIZ);
        d.name[DIRSIZ] = '\0';
        return &d;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    MY_DIR *dp = my_opendir(".");
    my_dirent *dent = my_readdir(dp);
    printf("directory info:\nname: %s; fd: %d; ino: %ld\n", dent->name, dp->fd, dent->ino);
}
```

I made debugging so I know why. As in comments, the while header

```
while(read(dp->fd, (char*) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
...
}
```

Is fails so the function returns NULL, which is dereferenced in printf. So the question is How to read that struct. I have found from `dir.h`

```
#define direct  dirent
```

So that structure is in effect `dirent`, which has following defintion `dirent.h`:

```
struct dirent
  {
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
    __ino_t d_ino;
    __off_t d_off;
#else
    __ino64_t d_ino;
    __off64_t d_off;
#endif
    unsigned short int d_reclen;
    unsigned char d_type;
    char d_name[256];       /* We must not include limits.h! */
  };
```

But that should not matter since, in `read(2)`, I am using `sizeof` which will get the proper size. So why does the `while` header fails?

Comment: You are making some assumptions that are not true:  1) You can `open()` and read a directory.  That's not always true.  2)  Your implementation of the structure matches what's read from the open directory.  [It flat-out won't](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle well, can I do something about it?

Comment: You're trying to reimplement Linux `getdents()` from glibc - so look at the source at https://github.com/bminor/glibc and see how it's implemented.  Note that figuring out how glibc implements *anything* is not trivial.

Comment: Ah, no easy solution I see

Comment: No, there isn't.  Glibc is so complex it can't even [make `fork()` async-signal-safe like every other OS that purports POSIX compliance](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161).  If the people who wrote and maintain it can't figure it out...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The [glibc implementation of `getdents` for Linux](https://sourceware.org/git?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getdents64.c;h=510a586859cb79c5d5dcb4531e1b23b7db06893a;hb=HEAD#l25) *is* trivial.  Linux has a `getdents` system call and the glibc function merely invokes it.  And that's what modern systems do instead of letting the library try to parse the on-disk format in user space.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that K&R 2 was written almost 35 years ago.  Besides discussing ANSI C aka C89, of which most (but not quite all) is still applicable to modern C, K&R also discuss many features that are not standardized but are specific to UNIX, or rather, to the UNIX of its day.

In former times, one would access directory entries as they do: by open()ing the directory like a file, and reading data from it in some specified format.  K&R themselves say that the format they use is specific to Version 7 and System V UNIX, so there is no reason at all to expect it to work with other versions of UNIX, much less with Linux which evolved completely independently.  In fact, the whole idea of using `read()` to get directory entries is now obsolete and generally not available.  The business of getting directory entries off the disk is done within the kernel, and it provides this data to user-space through more standardized APIs like `readdir` or `getdents`.

K&R is a classic and there is much to be learned from it, but its age does show and you cannot be surprised when some of what they say is not applicable to the present day.

---

Note when a system call fails, your first step in determining the reason should be to check the value of `errno`, perhaps using `perror()`.  If so, you would have seen that it was `EISDIR "Is a directory"`.  Referring to the `read(2)` man page indicates that this error occurs when "`fd` refers to a directory", implying that `read()` from a directory is generally not allowed.  That would at least have helped you shift your focus from "How to read that struct" to "since I can't read the struct, by what method should I be getting directory entries instead?"

Comment: Of course. I am not surprise. I am reading K&R2 as every C developer should. The fact it is old is okay. Other stuff there are valuable.